# Typescript type for final values in an object

Tags: typescript, types

I have a function where I want to have some static types that I want to use.

I have tried with `Type`, `interface`, `class`, `Record` etc.

but I can't seem to find the right fit

```js
const GEOLOCATIONS: Record<string, string> ={
    Canada: "CA",
    USA: "US",
    Denmark: "Da"
}

export const changeGeoLocation = async (location: keyof GEOLOCATIONS) => {
  const url = `${baseUrl}/en`;
  await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }).then(async (browser) => {
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    page.goto(url).then(async () => {
        const cookieValue = GEOLOCATIONS[location]
      await page.setCookie({ name: "ucISO", value:  });
      await page.reload();
    });
  });
};
```

the problem is that I both want to define the `location` argument as a `keyof` the values, so only the keys of the object can be passed in. Furthermore, I want to get the value from the key and set it as the value afterward.

What is the best type for this situation?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/N5EK5N), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  (e.g., no errors unrelated to your problem should be present.) This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: @jcalz yes the problem is that external dependencies are used, and this is more of a theoretical problem, so I think it's very much justified in this case.

Comment: You undoubtedly have very good reasons for leaving the code in question in the form you have it.  Nevertheless, not being able to immediately play around with it in an IDE is a barrier to entry for potential answerers.  If you can present a self-contained code example that displays the same sort of issue you're talking about, you will improve your chance of getting a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Record<string, string>` and use `keyof typeof GEOLOCATIONS` in the function signature.

```
const GEOLOCATIONS = {
    Canada: "CA",
    USA: "US",
    Denmark: "Da"
}

export const changeGeoLocation = (location: keyof typeof GEOLOCATIONS) => {
   ...
};
```

TSC then gives us `(parameter) location: "Canada" | "USA" | "Denmark"`.

TSC also tells us that `'GEOLOCATIONS' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof GEOLOCATIONS'?(2749)` in your original code, which is exactly what you need to do.